# Error in adding my own custom view to xml layout

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view in my application :

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);            
    }
    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
```

and I want to add this view to my activity's xml layout like this :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
     <test.example.myfirstapp.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/mostatil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_capture"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
     <Button
      android:id="@+id/button_capture"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
      android:onClick="capture"
      android:text="@string/capture_button" />
       </RelativeLayout>
```

but when I try to run this activity there are some errors like this:

```
01-06 14:26:00.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1933): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 14:26:00.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1933): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.example.myfirstapp/test.example.myfirstapp.CameraActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class test.example.myfirstapp.DrawView
```

my program's package name is test.example.myfirstapp and the xml file is for an activity named "CameraActivity"

EDIT :Here is some extra lines of logCat :

```
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class test.example.myfirstapp
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at test.example.myfirstapp.CameraActivity.onCreate(CameraActivity.java:77)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     ... 11 more
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "test.example.myfirstapp" on path: /data/app/test.example.myfirstapp-1.apk
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
01-06 14:16:20.708: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
```

when I open my XML layout in "Graphical Layout" mode, there's this error under the graphical layout :

```
   The following classes could not be instantiated:
    - test.example.myfirstapp.CameraActivity.DrawView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
    See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
    Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse
```

Comment: I recommend that you paste more of your logcat, as the actual stack trace will be below that `java.lang.RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paint should be instantiated in constructor

Answer (score 0):

While inflating a custom view in your xml first thing is don't forget to add this to your main view container

`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/my.package.name"` .

Second thing is just take a look if you are inflating your view with the right package name before it's name and check the spelling. If everything is correct.

Just copy and paste your whole xml file's code and on which package exactly your view is.

And be sure that you Override your `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method in your view..

**EDIT**

As I can see your xml look like this :

```
<test.example.myfirstapp
    android:id="@+id/mostatil"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_capture"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

but here you are not using your custom view, it should look like this :

```
<test.example.myfirstapp.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/mostatil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_capture"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

Comment: Remember that the `xmlns:app` is not required if your `View` does not have custom attributes loaded via XML.

Comment: It was a typing mistake, my xml file actually contains "DrawView" too

Comment: also, it's not even necessary to override `onDraw()`

Comment: so if you still got the same error show s what you have on your xml file line #13.

Comment: line #13 is the "<test.example.myfirstapp.DrawView" line

Comment: ok so something else, is your view declared in your activity as private class or it's in other package or something like that?

Comment: yeah but in your log it's still saying `test.example.myfirstapp`, please try again and update the logcat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22268/discussion-between-android-developer-and-navid777)

Comment: as i read in a few places, first try to restart your eclipse and run the project again

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean in eclipse, and uninstall the app from the device/emulator, then try again. Looks like your resources are messed up.

Comment: How can I do a clean in eclipse ?

Comment: Via Settings on the device/emulator.

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me:

in your .xml:

```
<view class="test.example.myfirstapp.DrawViewd"
android:id="@+id/mostatil"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_capture"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the class in a java class for itself instead of under a subclass.
Don't forget to update the XML tag.